# How to modify only the DESIGN temporarily (client-side) of an external site that I don't have directly access to?

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

It is a normal website that have a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) and a form which submit and check if the CAPTCHA is correct, then take the id and do a request for some information.

I do not have access to this site, and it is not mine. I need it to get the information, but the site does not have a good design, so I want to modify the design of the site to make it better to see, visually.

Can I do this?

I tried using PHP cUrl and jQuery $ajax with crossdomain true, but I got access denied on the two.

IMPORTANT: I want to do exactly what [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) does, temporary changes to a page layout, when you refresh you lose it because it is client-side.

Something like:

```
javascript:changeContent();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: why not? if i cant do that i need another idea, but i really have no option i need to do that.

Comment: @dandavis see again the question and re-answer.

Comment: if it's just for one computer that you control, use tampermonkey or greasmonkey to run your bookmarklet code automatically and without char count size limits.

Comment: Ok, but i am working using Delphi `TWebBrowser`, just by setting `TWebBrowser`.url to my javascript code. And my solution is wide because it works on every Browser manually and dinamically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I've found the solution to do this.

It's simpler that you think. I just created a JavaScript-native script that modify all the whole site elements, styles, widths, heights, and so, all by getting the "identifier" of the html elements.

My code:

```
javascript:function z(a,b,c,d,e,f,g){x=document.getElementsByTagName(a);
if(b!=null)x=x[b].getElementsByTagName(c);if(d!=null)x=x[d].getElementsByTagName(e);if(f!=null)x=x[f].getElementsByTagName(g);return x;}
function i(v){return document.getElementById(v).style;}
b=document.body.style;
b.backgroundColor="#f3f3f3";
b.margin="13% auto";
b.width="400px";
b.height="160px";
b.border="1px solid #CCCCCC";
b.padding="10px";
z("label")[0].style.fontFamily="Segoe UI";
z("label")[0].style.fontSize="13px";
z("label")[0].style.padding="0px 0px 10px 0px";
z("table")[0].style.display = "none";
z("hr")[0].style.display = "none";
z("p")[0].style.display = "none";
z("p")[1].style.display = "none";
z("p")[2].style.display = "none";
z("td")[1].style.display = "none";
document.getElementsByName("opcao")[0].style.display = "none";
i("submit1").float = "left";
z("label")[0].style.float = "left";
z("label")[0].style.display = "block";
z("td")[4].style.float = "left";
z("font")[6].face = "Segoe UI";
z("td")[4].style.display = "block";
z("td")[4].style.width = "250px";
z("td")[3].style.float = "left";
z("td")[3].style.width = "300px";
document.getElementsByName("captcha")[0].style.float = "left";
document.getElementsByName("captcha")[0].style.width = "140px";
z("td")[4].style.float = "left";
document.getElementById("submit1").value = "Insert Data";
k=i("submit1");
k.color="#fff";
k.backgroundColor="#FFAF19";
k.border="1px solid #CCCCCC";
k.height="34px";
k.width="165px";
```

**Maybe you are complaining about:**

What are those letters?? Why does the code use variables with one letter?
**Reply:** It's because you have a character-size limit to paste in the browser address bar of approximately 2000 characters.

Simplyfing, I used, for example:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('tag').getElementsByTagName('tag')[x];

//Like, for example:
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
//The first span of the first div.
```

Successively I did that to find elements and modify them, and:
I **created a function to do it for me in fewer characters.**

**That's why the code is so hard to understand.**

Then I just executed this code on the address bar of any browser, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can include the site using an iFrame. But you won't just be able to update it. If you could, then you could for every other site. Which means, you could just go on a site like Facebook and change things.

Access the DOM of an iFrame:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myframe'); // The id of the iFrame
var iFrame = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;
if (iFrame.document) { // DOM can be accessed
    iFrame = iFrame.document;
    iFrame.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; // Example
} else {
    // DOM can't be accessed in this browser.
}
```

I forgot. You can't access the DOM of an iFrame unless it is on your domain. `cross-site scripting` is not allowed at all. So the conclusion: This is not possible.

Comment: why i cant? i really need to do that, my chief asked me to do that and i'm trying to do it since 1 and half day...

Comment: "why i cant"...well it's pretty obvious why you can't. Because you need authorized access to change the code of a site.

Comment: Would you just want a random people to be able to change your site? AJAX is not going to work even with crossdomain.

Comment: Using firebug i can modify every site that i want in real-time using javascript, why i cant use programming to do that for me?

Comment: Dude, thats firebug. If you refresh, the changes arent saved.

Comment: I do not want to modify the original source code of the site, i just want to put a "face" into it, temporary. Client-side only

Comment: Some css style change and some change in the html too. I tried to create a page containing the layout that i want and a hidden iframe besides it but i cant change anything on the iframe

Comment: i can't create automatic firebug commands? or some javascript:"something" in the url to change temporary anything on the site?

Comment: You can use javascript. But, its gonna be a lot of work and its inefficient.

Comment: i got "Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'" when i execute your code, i dont matter if i need a lot of work to do that i just need to do. But i dont know how

Comment: Oh Yes, I forgot. You can't access the DOM of an iFrame unless it is on your domain. `cross-site scripting` is not allowed at all. So conclusion, this is not possible. Firebug works because it isn't updating the DOM of an iFrame. It is updating the actual site. JavaScript can do that. But you can't update the DOM of another site. You have to take the Facebook example again. You could just take an iFrame of Facebook and change and make it seem like your own social network.

Comment: But how i can act like firebug to modify something? (in code like javascript:something)

Comment: Listen dude, you can't. What do you not get about `cross-site scripting is not allowed`. Firebug is not working like JavaScript would on an iFrame. It is updating the actual site so it can update it. Just like with JavaScript you can update one of your domains. But you can't update another persons site. `NO CROSS-SITE SCRIPTING`.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Why don't you just make your own CAPTCHA or use Google's reCAPTCHA service rather than using someone else's? Are you trying to use another site's CAPTCHA, or what?

Comment: @Shawn31313 see again, i did edited my question and my answer, see if your answer are still valid.